# JDialog shows empty

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to replace the use of JOptionPane by a new custom dialog here is what I did:

```
    package pk;

    import java.util.Enumeration;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;

    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    import java.awt.SystemColor;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    import java.awt.Color;

    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

    public class SIMessage extends JDialog implements ActionListener{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public JButton oui=new JButton("Oui"),btnClose=new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\delete.gif")),
        non=new JButton("Non"),annuler=new JButton("Annuler"),ok=new JButton("OK"); 
        public JLabel lblImgErr=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgErreur.png")),
                lblImgConf=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgQuestion.png")),
                lblImgWarning=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgWarning.png")),
                lblImgInfo=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgInformation.png")),
                lblImgQuestion=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgQuestion.png")),
                lblImgIconApp=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\clntIco.ico"));
        public JLabel title=new JLabel(),message=new JLabel();

        public enum TypeMessage{
            ERROR_MESSAGE,
            CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE,
            WARNING_MESSAGE,
            INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            VALIDATION_MESSAGE
        }
        public SIMessage(JFrame parent,String title,TypeMessage type,String message) {
                 super(parent,true);
            setUndecorated(true); 
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

                JPanel mainDgPanel = new JPanel();
                mainDgPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(255, 255, 255), 3, true));
                mainDgPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 156);
                getContentPane().add(mainDgPanel);
                mainDgPanel.setLayout(null);
                mainDgPanel.setBackground(Color.decode(EcranPrincipal.blueThemeCP));

                JTextArea txtrTextarea = new JTextArea(message);
                txtrTextarea.setRows(2);
                txtrTextarea.setBounds(123, 62, 340, 80);
                txtrTextarea.setFont(new Font("Iskoola Pota", Font.PLAIN, 18));
                txtrTextarea.setEditable(false);
                txtrTextarea.setFocusable(false);
                txtrTextarea.setOpaque(false);
                txtrTextarea.setBorder(null);
                txtrTextarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                txtrTextarea.setLineWrap(true);
                txtrTextarea.setForeground(Color.decode(EcranPrincipal.blueThemeBT));
                mainDgPanel.add(txtrTextarea);

                JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();
                panelButtons.setBounds(47, 115, 344, 30);
                mainDgPanel.add(panelButtons);

                switch(type)
                {
                case ERROR_MESSAGE:
                    {
                        JLabel lblNewLabel =lblImgErr;
                        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                        mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                        JButton btnOk = ok;
                        panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                    break;
                    }
                case CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE:
                    {
                         JLabel lblNewLabel =lblImgConf;
                            lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                            mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                            JButton btnOui = oui;
                            panelButtons.add(btnOui);
                    break;
                    }
                case WARNING_MESSAGE:
                    {
                         JLabel lblNewLabel =lblImgWarning;
                            lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                            mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                            JButton btnOk = ok;
                            panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                    break;
                    }
                case INFORMATION_MESSAGE:
                    {
                         JLabel lblNewLabel =lblImgInfo;
                            lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                            mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                            JButton btnOk = ok;
                            panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                    break;
                    }
                case VALIDATION_MESSAGE:
                    {
                         JLabel lblNewLabel =lblImgConf;
                            lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                            mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);


                            JButton btnOui = oui;
                            panelButtons.add(btnOui);

                            JButton btnNon = non;
                            panelButtons.add(btnNon);

                            JButton btnAnnuler = annuler;
                            panelButtons.add(btnAnnuler);

                    break;
                    }
                    default:
                }
                ok.addActionListener(this);
                oui.addActionListener(this);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 27);
                mainDgPanel.add(panel);
                panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                panel.setLayout(null);

                JButton btnCloseDf = btnClose;
                btnCloseDf.setBounds(411, 0, 39, 23);
                panel.add(btnCloseDf);

                JLabel lblIconApp =lblImgIconApp;
                lblIconApp.setBounds(10, 4, 77, 14);
                panel.add(lblIconApp);

                JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
                lblTitle.setBounds(190, 4, 46, 14);
                panel.add(lblTitle);
                this.pack();
                this.setVisible(true);
        }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object source=e.getSource();
        if(source==oui||source==ok)
        {
            this.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Then I call:

```
    SIMessage sm=new SIMessage(this, "Attention", SIMessage.TypeMessage.WARNING_MESSAGE,"You need to change ...");
callMethode2();
```

The problem is that it executes the call to Methode2 before showing any dialog while it is supposed to force the user to respond before continuing.
I see an empty window side by side with the window generated by callMethod2!, so what is wrong?

Comment: `setLayout(null)` never ends well.

Comment: @trashgod I have just changed that to `getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1))` but no change!, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the **modality** for Dialog.

**A modal window** is a graphical control element subordinate to an application's main window. It creates a mode that disables the main window but keeps it visible with the modal window as a child window in front of it. Users must interact with the modal window before they can return to the parent application.

So, Set the modal flag of the dialog when initializing it.

```
setModal(True)
```

**edit:**
I don't know what you exactly changed in your code, but the code below works fine for me:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Emad
 */
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.SystemColor;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class SIMessage extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JButton oui = new JButton("Oui"), btnClose = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\delete.gif")),
            non = new JButton("Non"), annuler = new JButton("Annuler"), ok = new JButton("OK");
    public JLabel lblImgErr = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgErreur.png")),
            lblImgConf = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgQuestion.png")),
            lblImgWarning = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgWarning.png")),
            lblImgInfo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgInformation.png")),
            lblImgQuestion = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\msgQuestion.png")),
            lblImgIconApp = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("images\\logo\\clntIco.ico"));
    public JLabel title = new JLabel(), message = new JLabel();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == oui || source == ok) {
            this.dispose();
        }
    }

    public enum TypeMessage {
        ERROR_MESSAGE,
        CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE,
        WARNING_MESSAGE,
        INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
        VALIDATION_MESSAGE
    }

    public SIMessage(JFrame parent, String title, TypeMessage type, String message) {
        super(parent, true);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JPanel mainDgPanel = new JPanel();
        mainDgPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(255, 255, 255), 3, true));
        mainDgPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 156);
        getContentPane().add(mainDgPanel);
//                mainDgPanel.setBackground(Color.decode(EcranPrincipal.blueThemeCP));

        JTextArea txtrTextarea = new JTextArea(message);
        txtrTextarea.setRows(2);
        txtrTextarea.setBounds(123, 62, 340, 80);
        txtrTextarea.setFont(new Font("Iskoola Pota", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        txtrTextarea.setEditable(false);
        txtrTextarea.setFocusable(false);
        txtrTextarea.setOpaque(false);
        txtrTextarea.setBorder(null);
        txtrTextarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        txtrTextarea.setLineWrap(true);
//                txtrTextarea.setForeground(Color.decode(EcranPrincipal.blueThemeBT));
        mainDgPanel.add(txtrTextarea);

        JPanel panelButtons = new JPanel();
        panelButtons.setBounds(47, 115, 344, 30);
        mainDgPanel.add(panelButtons);

        switch (type) {
            case ERROR_MESSAGE: {
                JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgErr;
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                JButton btnOk = ok;
                panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                break;
            }
            case CONFIRMATION_MESSAGE: {
                JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgConf;
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                JButton btnOui = oui;
                panelButtons.add(btnOui);
                break;
            }
            case WARNING_MESSAGE: {
                JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgWarning;
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                JButton btnOk = ok;
                panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                break;
            }
            case INFORMATION_MESSAGE: {
                JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgInfo;
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                JButton btnOk = ok;
                panelButtons.add(btnOk);
                break;
            }
            case VALIDATION_MESSAGE: {
                JLabel lblNewLabel = lblImgConf;
                lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 69, 79, 14);
                mainDgPanel.add(lblNewLabel);

                JButton btnOui = oui;
                panelButtons.add(btnOui);

                JButton btnNon = non;
                panelButtons.add(btnNon);

                JButton btnAnnuler = annuler;
                panelButtons.add(btnAnnuler);

                break;
            }
            default:
        }
        ok.addActionListener(this);
        oui.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 444, 27);
        mainDgPanel.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnCloseDf = btnClose;
        btnCloseDf.setBounds(411, 0, 39, 23);
        panel.add(btnCloseDf);

        JLabel lblIconApp = lblImgIconApp;
        lblIconApp.setBounds(10, 4, 77, 14);
        panel.add(lblIconApp);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
        lblTitle.setBounds(190, 4, 46, 14);
        panel.add(lblTitle);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SIMessage sm=new SIMessage(null, "Attention", SIMessage.TypeMessage.WARNING_MESSAGE,"You need to change ...");
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Emad, I did that using `super(parent,true);` but now the dialog is there as skeleton not really accessible, but the main window is locked!

Comment: Remove the line `mainDgPanel.setLayout(null);`. Dialog should contain a layout. the default layout is flowLayout.

Comment: I replaced all nulls with new BorderLayout() but it is still blocked.

Comment: You should add an action listener to ok button, and dispose the dialog when user click on ok.

Comment: @SEVOIDEM I had added the code to answer, check it out!

Comment: Thank you for commenting these two lines of my code, they were looking at a color of my theme, using a class that has not been instantiated yet `EcranPrincipal`, now it works!!! thanks.